# How to install/setup/use navigation stack

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have built a MIT-Racecar which has ROS, ubuntu, Ackermann and VESC. The car can be driven with a teleop who sends out ackermann_msgs/AckermannDriveStamped type messages in ROS. The car also publishes /tf, /odom, hokuyo 2D LiDar related /scan messages, and ZED stereo camera related image and camera message.

I am a little confused about what exactly I need to do next to make it autonomous. After reading the navigation stack tutorial on ROS Wiki, I think I need to do the following:

1. Install the navigation stack by

   sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-navigation
2. Create a ros package under my MIT-Racecar workspace and setup the config and launch files as described in http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup
3. Since I am using Ackermann, I need to install and setup teb_local_planner.
4. Run the stack with launch file generate in 2 by

   Terminal 1: roslaunch my_robot_configuration.launch

   Terminal 2: roslaunch move_base.launch
5. Use teleop to drive the car around to map the environment I am in (probably need to set some flag when I run the command in 4).
6. Run command in 4 in localization mode.
7. Set a gaol for the car, and then it will drive there autonomously.

Am I correctly in these steps?

Thank y ou very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296575/how-to-install/setup/use-navigation-stack/) by [AutoCar](https://answers.ros.org/users/35903/autocar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 102 on 2018-07-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

yes you are correct. you can get a better idea of how this all works with the [clearpath husky demo](http://www.clearpathrobotics.com/assets/guides/husky/HuskyGmapping.html)

Try running the mapping tutorial, then the amcl tutorial and you will have a basic understanding of how the navigation stack works. When you use your own robot, its just a matter of a different launch configuration.

---

Originally posted by [aarontan](https://answers.ros.org/users/35174/aarontan/) with karma: 135 on 2018-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AutoCar](https://answers.ros.org/users/35903/autocar/) on 2018-07-07**:
What SLAM algo does the ROS navigation stack use? gmapping, hector, ...

**Comment by [aarontan](https://answers.ros.org/users/35174/aarontan/) on 2018-07-08**:
this depends on you, if you go through the husky clearpath demo, they use gmapping

**Comment by [AutoCar](https://answers.ros.org/users/35903/autocar/) on 2018-07-15**:
If I install the ROS navigation stack by sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-navigation, does it install gmapping? Or I have to install gmapping separately?

**Comment by [aarontan](https://answers.ros.org/users/35174/aarontan/) on 2018-07-16**:
yes i believe it should